# Creating a grow and nudge effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wasn't sure if this question is ok or not, its a bit of a grey area.

I want to create an effect similar to the one seen in [in this example profile](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/sample)

now I need help with one bit of this, I know that all the divs are in a container with a fixed width but when you hover over them they grow out of the main container div.. I noticed that they are position relative that explains how the flow of the document is maintained and the div can break out of the container..while they float left.

I will use .animate to grow the div, and .fadeTo to fade out the other divs ($('.box.).not(this).. etc.

I will supply a code example later today.

I was wondering if anyone knew how the other divs get pushed aside or a good method of doing this

Comment: Looks to me like the div ids are in focus for a hover. what about $(#id).focus() ?

Comment: interesting question but you should really post some code with your attempt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS and javascript. On hover of one of the div elements, the other elements are given a class slide-down/slide-up/slide-right/slide-left depending on the other div elements locations relative to the mouseover div element. e.g., when given the class slide-down:

```
.slide-down .animate {
top: 10px;
}
```

In order to achieve the fade this css is being used:

```
.slide-down .animate, .slide-up .animate, .slide-right .animate, .slide-left .animate {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40);
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

I can't find the javascript that makes the class changes but it should be pretty simple to recreate using either javascript or jQuery.

Comment: so I would have to work out the if the current div has other divs above or beside it and append the correct classes to them?

Comment: Yeah, you can use jQuery to respond to mouseover/mouseout and then use jQuery Traversing API's to look for all matching prev/next elements of the current div.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/d8BuH/

Very simple example.  I used margins and floats instead of the classes based approach.  This one you would not have has much control over but the code is MUCH simpler.  So if you are looking for a cool simple effect this may work for you.